# How does one write maintainable Solr code?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

In our project we have a solr schema that has values with mutiple, near-duplicate fields. What I mean by this is we have an example field **Field** which we store as **field**, **field_w** and **field_l** in solr and each of them have different boost factors in search (the dynamic types are not _w or _l but similar).

As a result, we have a **Model** which we map to **SolrSchemaModel** through custom code, which we then store in Solr. When we read from Solr we then read **SolrDocumentList** (not **SolrSchemaModel** as it has embedded documents which are mapped to **__childDocuments__** on read) and construct a **ModelSearchResponse** (not a **Model** as it has missing fields).

As you can see this is going to lead to a **lot** of maintenance whenever we want to add fields to **Model** and if we want to change the schema we also need to change **SolrSchemaModel** AND all the code mapping to and from it.

How have others handled persistence with Solr? One idea bouncing around was to have a JSON serialisation of the class as a Solr field, that way write is changed whenever the schema or **Model** changes and the serialisation/deserialisation remains intact. Another person suggested not using Solr as persistence only having something separate (which I guess would mean performing reads on another database after performing searches before returning results).

How have people solved this? Using *Java 8* with *SolrJ* if that is relevant.

Comment: We save serialized JSON in solr and deserialize them during returning.  It's ok if you don't have a huge document.

Comment: I see. So when you write to solr you are storing all the searchable fields and when reading you only read one field, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of things here:

1. If you are copying fields to other fields for different analysis, you don't need to **store** other fields, just index them. So, you only need to **copyField** them on Solr level and not change your serialization model.
2. The classical way to deal with not needing to track schema equivalence is dynamic fields with prefix or suffix in the names indicating types. So, all *_s fields are strings and all *_d fields are dates. Your mapper could probably even suffix/unsuffix automatically. That's what most CMSs use when talking to Solr.
3. copyField supports wildcards for source and target fields, so you can still combine the techniques above.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for. I wasn't aware of copy field :-)

Comment: It is all over the examples. If you read schema.xml, it shows all the interesting things you can learn (e.g. dynamicField *, commented out). You just need to give it time, as the examples have grown and became quite large over time.